# Como percorrer ArrayList com classe filha

Tags: java, array, lista, herança

Seguinte, eu tenho um `ArrayList` do tipo Estudante (que é uma classe abstrata), e tenho duas classes filhas (`EstudanteGraduacao` e `EstudantePosGraduacao`), quando vou adicionar eles ao `ArrayList` é tranquilo, mas como faço para percorrer ele com um objeto das filhas?
Por exemplo quando faço:

```
for(Estudante e : estudantes){
    return e.getX();
    // considerando getX um metodo de Estudante
}
```

ele funciona, o problema é que não sei como acessar os métodos do `EstudanteGraduacao`...

Enfim, espero que tenha sido claro, agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Não seria o caso de você adicionar métodos abstratos na superclasse estudante que representem as operações comuns de cada subclasse? Se a superclasse é uma classe vazia, pode ser que seu modelo utilizando herança não seja o mais adequado.

Answer (score 0):

Tens que fazer o cast para estudantegraduacao

```
((EstudanteGraduacao) e).getX()
```

Mas cuidado, se todos os estudantes do array não forem EstudanteGraduacao o método getX() vai fazer o throw de ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é utilizar o `instanceof` antes de executar alguma operação.
Se o elemento do array for `instanceof(EstudanteGraduacao)` então é possível chamar um método do tipo `EstudanteGraduacao`.

Answer (score -2):

Para resolver esta pergunta, irei fazer a classe abstrata `Estudante` e seus derivados `EstudanteGraduacao` e `EstudantePosGraduacao`.

```
public abstract class Estudante{
        public abstract Object getX();
        public abstract void print(); //Para complementar.
}

public class EstudanteGraduacao extends Estudante{
       public Object getX() {
            return new Object();
       }
       public void print(){
            System.out.println("Estudante de Graduação");
       }
}

public class EstudantePosGraduacao extends Estudante{
       public Object getX() {
            return new Object();
       }
       public void print(){
            System.out.println("Estudante de Pós Graduação");
       }
}
```

Supondo que tenho uma `ArrayList<Estudante>` que pode conter essas classes derivadas poderá utilizar o `instanceof`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     ArrayList<Estudante> estudantes = new ArrayList<>();
     //Adicione os estudantes...
     for(Estudante e : estudantes){
         if(e instanceof EstudanteGraduacao){
              ((EstudanteGraduacao)e).print(); //ou use de forma direta depois que checar se é desse tipo.
              //Fazer algo com o objeto e ((EstudanteGraduacao)e).getX();
         } else if(e instanceof EstudantePosGraduacao){
              ((EstudantePosGraduacao)e).print();
              //Fazer algo com o objeto e ((EstudantePosGraduacao)e).getX();
         }
     }

}
```

Para compreender, por exemplo, o `Object` é a classe base do Java (igual ao `object` no C#) e armazena dados de tipo desconhecido como `String`, `int`, `double`, `float`, `boolean`, entre outros. Supondo que numa variável de `Object` é um inteiro, para isso deve se verificar se pode atribuir um `int` ou `Integer` pelo um `Object` usando:

```
if(obj instanceof int){//Não se dever usar palavra-chave nessa expressão
    //...
}

//Deve usar a classe Wrapper dele: o Integer.
Object obj = 5;
if(obj instanceof Integer){
    //Continua....
} else{
    throw new Exception("Use uma mesagem para descrever que deve ser inteiro.");
}

//Dica: Para arrays utilize (obj instanceof Tipo[])
```

*Envie comentários se quer complementar algo não citado.*